# jquery - JSON to <table>

Tags: jquery

I have Json of the form

```
[{"id":39,"data":1},{"id":40,"data":2}]
```

It does not parse properly with `jQuery.parseJSON()`

I need to take this data and create a html `table`.  I was thinking of creating the  HTML dynamically in the js.

A.  How can I parse the json?
B.  Is dynamic html the best route?

**Update** 
I apologize.  Evidently my question is not clear.  Here is the jquery

```
 $.get('Service.aspx',
    { p1: value, p2: value },
    function (data) {
        notesJson = data;
        alert(notesJson);//Json comes back as I said here...
        var noteSet = jQuery.parseJSON(notesJson);
        alert(noteSet.notes);                      
 });
```

notes does exist in the Json.
The second alert fails "undefined".

Comment: where is the JSON coming from?

Comment: @Neal $.get request sent to ASP.NET page which uses JavaScriptSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: $.parseJSON('[{"id":39,"data":1},{"id":40,"data":2}]'); worked in FF console for me. How is it not working correctly for you? Errors, null objects? What browser is giving you issues.

Comment: Are you looking for noteSet[0].notes? based on the description of your data format noteSet would be an array of objects.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey i edited my answer based on your update

Comment: and i see no element in your jQuery called `notes`

Comment: Well...Somebody had an answer up and suggested I use $getJson() and a table reference.  This worked wonderfully!! But now they deleted or changed the answer so I cant give them credit...I think it was @Neal

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok based on you comment on your question:

Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`:

```
$.getJSON('someurl', {/*somedata*/}, function(json_data){

    //no need for parsejson
    //use the json_data object

    var table_obj = $('table');
    $.each(json_data, function(index, item){
         var table_row = $('<tr>', {id: item.id});
         var table_cell = $('<td>', {html: item.data});
         table_row.append(table_cell);
         table_obj.append(table_row);
    })

})
```

Comment: Instead of using string literals as in Neal's answer, there are quite a few javascript templating libraries you can use. [Microjs](http://microjs.com/#templating) lists quite a few and there's also [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Comment: I used your original answer.  The $.getJson was spot on and simple.

Comment: i rolled back to that original answer

Answer (score 5):

What you have is an array, you need an object.  Try

```
 { "notes" : [{"id":39,"data":1},{"id":40,"data":2}] }
```

as the json

or do this

```
  alert(noteSet[0]);
  alert(noteSet[1]);
```

Comment: AFAIK - I do not have control over the way .NET serializes Json.  I am using JavaScriptSerializer class in ASP.NET

Comment: @P.Brain This is because you are using the .get function I believe.  If you use .ajax you can specify protocol and this works better with .net  Also, you could wrap your results or use the json serializer.

Comment: @Hogan you can specify the protocol with `.get` as well when passing in the last argument.

Comment: @Neal - did I just time travel 20 months?

Comment: Yep. yes you did ^_^ all timey wimey

Answer (score 2):

Here's another good library to simply achieve that: 
https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table

Just pass the JSON data to this library and get the HTML table:

```
//Only first parameter is required
var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(objectArray, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using .NET so you could use

```
return Json(yourObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of JavaScriptSerializer.
You won't have to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

A jquery plugin that accepts JSON data to fill a table could do. [jsonTable](https://github.com/omkarkhair/jsonTable)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way taking into account the headings of the table for a typical database query. Based on Neil's answer:

```
$.getJSON('bower.json', {}, function(json_data) {
            var table = $('table');
            $.each(json_data, function(key, item) {
                var table_row = $('<tr>');
                $.each(item, function(itemKey, itemValue) {
                    if (key == 0) {
                        table.append($('<th>', {html: itemKey}));
                    }
                    table_row.append($('<td>', {html: itemValue}));
                });
                table.append(table_row);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this full code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $.getJSON('URL', function(json_data){

        var table_obj = $('table');
        $.each(json_data, function(index, result){
             var table_row = $('<tr>', {});
             var table_cell1 = $('<td>', {html: result.firstName});//result.yourDataAttributes
             var table_cell2 = $('<td>', {html: result.lastName});
             var table_cell3 = $('<td>', {html: result.age});
             table_row.append(table_cell1,table_cell2,table_cell3);
             table_obj.append(table_row);
        })

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
<table id=""></table> 
</body>
```