# jQuery Ajax does not update the result inside the div

Tags: html, jquery

This question might be basic for most of the people out here, but I'm really fed up of           not getting the desired o/p. I want to make AJAX calls when an item from the list(id = vzlabs_data) is being clicked and its respective data should be updated inside the table(id = table_data).

Currently, I'm able to POST the data, make the db calls against it, fetches it data and the data fetched is being printed in the python interpreter but is not updated inside the table.

Where I'm going wrong?

**HTML template**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav" id="nav_bar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#device">Device</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#content">Content</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#help">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">From :
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />To :
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 pull-left">//****** An item is picked up from this list**********
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked"
            id="vzlabs_data">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">All Data</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">VZW3RD</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">VZWLAB</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">VZW2ND</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end of div span2-->
        <div id="pie_chart" class="span4" style="height: 275px"></div>
        <!-- end of div span4-->
        <div class="span5">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="table_data">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Categories</th>
                        <th>Subscribers</th>
                        <th>Rate(bps)</th>
                        <th>Tonage(Bytes)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>// Data is updated over here. {% for key, value in vzlab_data.items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{key}}</td>
                        <td>{{value.subscriber}}</td>
                        <td>{{value.rate_bps}}</td>
                        <td>{{value.tonage_bytes}}
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>{%endfor%}</tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- end of div span7-->
    </div>
    <!-- end of div row-->
```

**JS function**

```
$(function () {
    $("#vzlabs_data li").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data: {
                'lab': $(this).text()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#table_data").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):
    vzlab_data = get_vzlab_data("All Data")

    if request.is_ajax():
        lab           = request.POST['lab']
        vzlab_data    = get_vzlab_data(lab)
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(vzlab_data), mimetype='application/javascript')


ctx = {'vzlab_data' : vzlab_data}

return render_to_response('dashboard/dashboard1.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I suggest debugging the result parameter in your ajax 'success' callback. That might give you an insight of what happened on the server side. Also you might try using Google Chrome's Network feature in the Developers tools or similar tool using Firefox plugin FireBug

Comment: Well, what I feel there is something wrong with my sending off data back to the client-side from my python script. is it really should be like `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(vzlab_data), mimetype='application/javascript')` because the `success` function doesnt works with this and on removing it, the success functions works by returning the whole page again via `render_to_response` command. Kindly check whether I'm sending the data correctly or not?

Comment: unfortunatelly I am not a Python developer... What response do you get from server, though? What is contained in the result parameter? Is it completely empty? Also you're not telling in the $.ajax() method what kind of response from server you expect.. Do you expect JSON response, or XML or plain text?

Comment: The response I get is off the json form. Here is my response `{"Technology and Computing": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 11.1, "rate_bps": 2.12}, "Education": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 143.2, "rate_bps": 1.69}, "Arts and Entertainment": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 929.3, "rate_bps": 1.67}, "Miscellaneous": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 149.0, "rate_bps": 1.26}}. `

Comment: since this is a JSON string and not an HTML code, it can't be appended to HTML. Check details in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK you are apparently getting JSON result. So your $.ajax() method should contain that it expects 'JSON' data type. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dashboard/",
    data: {
        'lab': $(this).text()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        // THIS IS ACTUALLY WRONG
        //$("#table_data").html(result);
    }
});
```

Then you need to parse the JSON and build it into HTML string. Now, if you're getting 'result' as json string (it should be a javascript associative array though, If I'm not mistaken), you have to convert it to associative array: `var resultObj = JSON.parse(json)`

And then you can build HTML string in Javascript and use that builded string to actually:

```
$("#table_data").html(yourBuildedString);
```

'Final' version of the code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/dashboard/",
  data: {
    'lab': $(this).text()
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (result) {
    // ok you don't need to do this, jquery already converted json into Javascript object for you
    //var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);

    // parsing the resultObj into string, just example, you have to do it yourself
    // var parsedTableContent = "<tr><td>"+result['Education']['subscriber']+"</td><td>"+result['Education']['tonage_bytes']+"</td></tr>"
    $("#table_data").html(parsedTableContent);
  }
});
```

Just one more thing, I've noticed that in your response there are keys like this one: Technology and Computing

As a good practice you might want to avoid using spaces in array keys in the future

Comment: Where does the `var resultObj = JSON.parse(json)` goes? Inside the `success` function? Can you please provide me with a rectified code for the same?

Comment: `result['subscriber']` and `result['tonage_bytes']` both are being read as `undefined`? Why?

Comment: It should be `result['Education']['subscriber']`.

Comment: I'll update the answer with appropriate array keys, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

Set the `dataType` attribute to the type of data being returned.
 If `json` object is returned it wont get displayed inside html,

Try to alert the response to check whether it returns a response

put this inside your success function

```
 // let's say you have an object like = {  number: { ... } } in your JSON data
    var html="";

              html += '<tr><td>'+result.number+'</td></tr>';
              html +=  '<tr><td>'+result.name+'</td></tr>';  // another object name

$('#table_data').html(html);
```

Comment: I added `dataType: "json",` and tested with `alert(result)` inside the success function. It returns `[object Object]` as the text inside the alert dialog box. Plus after the AJAx request, the table is now not being shown.

Comment: yeah it wont be displayed in the html like that if it is json object

Comment: I have edited my code , first identify the json object name that is returned  from your server. eg: number in the above   .. and dont forget to add attribute dataType:"json"  in your ajax call

Comment: How do I identify the json object name returned?

Comment: post your server side coding

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#table_data").html(result);
    $("#table_data").trigger('create');//To refresh the page content on success call back

}
```

If you are using latest version then `.trigger('create')` is depreciated. Instead use :

```
 $("#table_data").page();
```

Also just to ensure you are getting the result on success callback, try `console.log(result);`.

So :

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $("#table_data").html(result);
    $("#table_data").trigger('create');//To refresh the page content on success call back

}
```

Comment: I'll give it try. In the meanwhile kindly check whether `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(vzlab_data), mimetype='application/javascript')` is the correct way of returning the data or not?

Comment: Well, I tried your solution but to no luck. I've tried firebug earlier as well and in the `response` tab under `console`, the data is being received, but it is not being updated inside the table.

Comment: Here it is :- `{"Technology and Computing": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 11.1, "rate_bps": 2.12}, "Education": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 143.2, "rate_bps": 1.69}, "Arts and Entertainment": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 929.3, "rate_bps": 1.67}, "Miscellaneous": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 149.0, "rate_bps": 1.26}}`

Comment: You are trying to add this as html? Wont work.. Either you format this in html from your server page. Or pass this data to your view and by looping through the result, display everything you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If the data returned in `result` is not tabular data (e.g. does not consist of data in the form `<tr>...</tr>` or `<tbody>...</tbody>` with all the neccesary rows and cells, then the browser won't display it in the table.

Can you post the actual data returned in `result`?

Comment: this should be a comment to the question though, not an answer, since it really doesn't answer the OP's question :)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Here is the type of data returned. `{"Technology and Computing": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 11.1, "rate_bps": 2.12}, "Education": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 143.2, "rate_bps": 1.69}, "Arts and Entertainment": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 929.3, "rate_bps": 1.67}, "Miscellaneous": {"subscriber": 1, "tonage_bytes": 149.0, "rate_bps": 1.26}}`

Comment: Can't comment, not enough rep :)

Comment: That's not tabluar data so you can't insert it directly into table HTML. You need to format it into valid table contents first.

Comment: and how will I do that? Any tutorial links for the same?

Comment: There is a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996805/jquery-json-to-table