# How do I append jQuery.ajax data to a table?

Tags: jquery

The data I am getting from `$.ajax` is in this format:

```
{
    "rows":[
        {"key":["aaa"], "value":240363},
        {"key":["sss"], "value":29},
        {"key":["ddd"], "value":240363},
        {"key":["fff"], "value":240363},
        {"key":["ggg"], "value":240363},
        {"key":["hhh"], "value":240363},
        {"key":["jjj"], "value":240363}
    ]
}
```

How can I append it to a table in html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - JSON to <table>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996805/jquery-json-to-table)

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<table id="my_table"></table>
```

Jquery code:

```
$ajax(
    url: some_url_here
    // other params
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.rows, function(index, item){
            $('#my_table').append('<tr><td>'+item.key[0]+'</td><td>'+item.value+'</td></tr>');
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was receiving a text rather than a json object.
i used $.getJSON instead  and the problem was solved.
you can view your object by console.log(data) on order to access the parts you need from the data.